# using feature in Rspec generating an error

Tags: ruby, rspec, integration

I read the following article about using Rspec for feature tests:

https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/how-we-write-readable-feature-tests-with-rspec/

I tried the following after installing the `capybara` gem and got an error:

```
=> schedule_kaya_spec.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `feature' for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my code:

```
RSpec.feature "Create recurring event and get slack via cron next day" , :type => :feature  do

    scenario "User creates a daily recurring event at 10AM PST" do

        given_a_user_has_created_a_recurring_slack_event_at_10_pst

        when_the_time_passes_10_pst_the_next_day

        then_send_a_slack_message

        and_update_next_occurrence_for_the_next_day

    end


    def given_a_user_has_created_a_recurring_slack_event_at_10_pst

        # set time to 10AM PST
        Time.zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
        Chronic.time_class = Time.zone
        Timecop.freeze(Chronic.parse("march 1, 2014 at 10AM")) 

        user_input = "xtest create recurring event at 10 AM PST everyday with keyword test reminder keyword"
        bot_client_id = 'test-client-id'

        bot_response = BotResponse.new(bot_client_id, user_input, "1000")

        bot_response.run

    end
```

**Question:**
1) How can I create feature/scenario tests using methods like below?
2) Is there a way I can make `feature` more like describe and have multiple features with nested scenarios?

Comment: I made some traction by replacing `feature` with `describe` and `scenario` with `it`.....would be more readable if I could interachange, which I thought was possible.

Comment: What version of RSpec do you use? Do you have rspec-rails installed?

Comment: No I am writing in just ruby. I read that people with ruby rails has his. Is that a gem?

Comment: Rspec gem doesn't define a version so I think it should be the latest stable build.

Comment: Yep, `rspec-rails` is a gem, you can look into some documentation on it here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails. To find out gem version you can run `bundle show rspec-rails`.